# Отложенная загрузка Yandex карт API

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Коллеги, добрый день
На сайте использую Яндекс карту API.
Подключаю через script, в src указываю предоставленный путь от Яндекс.
Карта работает и отображает. Но встал вопрос о производительности, а именно о скорости загрузки сайта.
Помимо я использую скрипт для кастомизации карты:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
   function init() {
      let siteMap = new ymaps.Map("site-map", {
         center: [55.80471227396373, 37.58956129496764],
         zoom: 17
      });

      let placemark = new ymaps.Placemark([55.80468810353046, 37.5902586693115], {}, {
         iconLayout: 'default#image',
         iconImageHref: '../icons/icon.svg',
         iconImageSize: [70, 70]
      });

      siteMap.behaviors.disable('scrollZoom');

      siteMap.controls.remove('geolocationControl');
      siteMap.controls.remove('searchControl');
      siteMap.controls.remove('trafficControl');
      siteMap.controls.remove('typeSelector');
      siteMap.controls.remove('fullscreenControl');
      siteMap.controls.remove('zoomControl');
      siteMap.controls.remove('rulerControl');
      siteMap.controls.remove(['scrollZoom']);
      siteMap.geoObjects.add(placemark);
   }

   ymaps.ready(init);
});
```

Для отложенной загрузки, на просторах интернетов нашел следующий скрипт:

```
let ok = false;                    
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    if (ok === false) {
        ok = true;    
        setTimeout(() => {                    
            let script = document.createElement('script');
            script.src = 'https://api-maps.yandex.ru/services/constructor/1.0/js/?um=constructor%3A2467dfbbd414306f38c00aa9048346ada3bf2ae105b1d1c84eb6a671b54fc5cd&amp;width=100%25&amp;height=300&amp;lang=ru_RU&amp;scroll=false';
            document.getElementById('site-map').replaceWith(script);                        
        }, 1000)    
    }
});
```

В script.src я использую выше мной упомянутый путь предоставленный Яндексом, но вместо карты на странице вижу пустой блок.

Подскажите пожалуйста кто сталкивался с подобной задачей? Может есть какое-то другое решение?

Спасибо

Comment: Не надо постоянно выдумывать откладывание загрузки, поскольку скрипт и так берётся из кэша. При однократной загрузке API Яндекс Карт на любом сайте она сохраняется в кэш и на любом другом сайте грузится уже не из сети. Зачем откладывать локальную загрузку?

Comment: @YaCor' такая необходимость возникла из-за того, что сайт проходит проверку на скорость загрузки с показателем ниже среднего. Поэтому возникла такая необходимость.

Comment: Не следует доверять этим анализаторам, если речь заходит о реальной работе с сайтом и пользователями. Но в целом можно перенести вызов init() в задержку. Тогда после скролла и ожидаемой ошибки вызова ещё не загруженного ymaps карта всё равно загружается. https://jsbin.com/hezazim/edit?js,output

Comment: @YaCor' дело в том, что, если я использую свою ссылку с идентификатором от Яндекса, то карта не прогружается.

Comment: Что значит "свою ссылку с идентификатором от Яндекса"? Покажите, чем ваш код отличается от предложенного мной выше, который работает?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение, как и в большинстве случаев оказалось на поверхности (следует внимательнее читать документацию API Yandex карты).

Из скрипта необходимо было убрать слушатель события DOMContentLoaded. Без него все работает.

Answer (score 0):

После того, как сработает `document.getElementById('site-map').replaceWith(script);` на странице больше нет элемента с id = 'site-map'.

Поэтому

```
let siteMap = new ymaps.Map("site-map", {
         center: [55.80471227396373, 37.58956129496764],
         zoom: 17
      });
```

не срабатывает.

Comment: да, я понимаю. Я менял строку document.getElementById('site-map').replaceWith(script); и добавлял script в конец документа. Но опять же ничего не работало.

Comment: При подключении скрипта используйте параметр onload: https://yandex.ru/dev/jsapi-v2-1/doc/ru/v2-1/dg/concepts/load

Comment: к сожалению скорость загрузки все так же оставляет желать лучшего.